# SQL Results to Powershell HTML Document

Tags: html, sql-server, powershell

I have a SQL record set that I pulled from our internal project management software that has HTML tags in it. I would like to take this record set and create a HTML document with Powershell that follows the format of the tags. Is it possible to do this?

I tried this code:

```
$VersionNotes = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $svr -Database $database -Query $versionSQL 

$VersionNotes | Select-Object Name, ReleaseNotes | ConvertTo-Html |  Out-File c:\temp\htmltest.htm
Invoke-Expression C:\Temp\htmltest.htm
```

But it just returns the SQL results unformated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this ..

```
$VersionNotes = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $svr -Database $database -Query $versionSQL 

$Html = $VersionNotes | Select-Object Name, ReleaseNotes | ConvertTo-Html | Out-String 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.web") | Out-Null
$Html = [System.Web.Httputility]::HtmlDecode($Html)

ConvertTo-HTML  -PostContent $Html | Out-File C:\Temp\htmltest.htm
Invoke-Expression C:\Temp\htmltest.htm
```

More details [How to make SQL results to HTML document using PowerShell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-make-SQL-results-to-52f7e330)